# Indexing a varchar2 column in oracle with a pattern?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have a problem on indexing oracle

Following SQL query is given (means, it is automatically generated, I can't adapt it):

```
select * from t where f like 'AA.%.123456.%'
```

On column f, a unique index exists, but it is not beeing used by the oracle optimizer (it's doing a full table scan)

I think this because of the data

Data in column f allways begin with AA

Please note following data example:

```
AA.248117.123456.UAAA
AA.741447.123456.UAAA
AA.741449.123456.UAAA
AA.741450.123456.UAAA
AA.322812.123456.UAAA
AA.741363.123456.UZZZ
AA.741365.123456.UZZZ
AA.356110.123456.UZZZ
AA.356333.456789.UBBB
AA.256321.456789.UBBB
AA.333219.456789.UBBX
```

My question:
Is it possible to create an oracle index with a string-pattern?

Meaning a index as some kind of substring (but not using a function based index Substr(), as mentioned above, I can't change the query)

Index should look like this

```
'AA.<someNumberNotRelevant>.<indexedValue>.<someStringNotRelevant>'
```

Thanks

Comment: You can create an index on an expression, but I don't think this works for a boolean expression.  Hence, that approach would require rewriting the query.

Comment: I think your correct, the Full table scan may be more optimal if the stats on the column indicate higher than 20 percent or so start with AA. If you switch to ZZ does it switch. Do you have stats. I don't think what you want is possible . May need to split into other columns if possible

Comment: You could try an Optimizer hint, so something like select /*+ index(t your_index) */ * from t;

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Unfortunatelly all rows start with AA (100%). And unfortunatelly I can't rewrite the query, so I can't add a use index hint. It would result in a index range scan with a huge cardinality, I don't know if it would really be faster. I will read about index on a expression.

Comment: The reason the Optimizer chooses a full table scan is due to the comparison - and if that is the comparison you need, you can't do anything about it. The problem is the wildcard **%** followed by more hard-coded characters. This has nothing to do with what index you would define on that column, or with how selective the LIKE condition is.

Comment: On the other hand: Is the format always **exactly** the same (four parts, separated by periods), and are you looking to select rows where the third part out of four is a given value? You can write a function-based index for that, but you will need to modify the condition in the WHERE clause. NOW: You said you can't change the query. **Why not?**

Comment: Just on the off chance... if 'AA.%.123456.%' is a constant value in your program (i.e., it never changes and is passed verbatim in the SQL rather than as a bind value), then you can solve this easily using `DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE.DECLARE_REWRITE_EQUIVALENCE`.  I imagine that's not the case though...

Comment: If your value (e.g., 'AA.%.123456.%') changes in each run, you could look into using `DBMS_SQL_TRANSLATOR` to automatically rewrite it for you at run-time.  If I get any time (ha), I may figure it out.